# downloading pygame dependencies with homebrew; config.py file doesn't recognize them

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pygame, homebrew

Another tedious pygame install (on osx) question but I've searched far and wide and haven't been able to find an answer to this particular issue. When I run config.py here's my output:

```
Hunting dependencies...
Framework SDL not found
Framework SDL_ttf not found
Framework SDL_image not found
Framework SDL_mixer not found
Framework smpeg not found
PNG     : found
JPEG    : found
SCRAP   : not found
PORTMIDI: not found
Framework CoreMidi found
```

I've downloaded via homebrew the appropriate dependencies:

```
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf smpeg portmidi
```

Here's my brewlist:

```
atk         gobject-introspection   pixman
autoconf        gtk+            pkg-config
automake        harfbuzz        portmidi
cairo           icu4c           python
cmake           jpeg            readline
fontconfig      libffi          sdl
freetype        libpng          sdl_mixer
gdbm            libtiff         sdl_ttf
gdk-pixbuf      libtool         smpeg
gettext         mercurial       sqlite
git         openssl
glib            pango
```

Note: You can see SDL_image is missing my computer is freezing at the Make step during install but that is a whole other issue.

If anyone can give me any guidance as to how to get my config.py file to recognize these dependencies I'd be very thankful.

Second note: I have tried installing pygame itself through: pip, homebrew and downloading the package.